# How to get/generate HMAC-SHA1 signature for Twitter in PHP using TwitterOAuth (abraham/twitteroauth)

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, hmacsha1

I am trying to generate my signature with `HMAC-SHA1` as suggested by the Twitter documentation.

But I am using the **abraham/twitteroauth** package to make this "easier" and I leave a screenshot of what it is returning to me.

[image]

And the package really works.

Note: What I want to do is RT and FAV to other Tweets from other users. In addition to that, create replies.

Any ideas what can I do or how can I generate this signature?

I tried it with POSTMAN (the one provided by Twitter) and it works there, but it doesn't work in my code.

The data to generate the signature are:

- consumer_key
- consumer_secret
- access_token
- token_secret

[image]

I am also pointing to the endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/retweets

Comment: Can you describe the error or issue? You're saying that using the TwitterOAuth package works, so you could use that?

Comment: @AndyPiper I would like to know how to generate the signature without using packages.

Answer (score 0):

Although **I would like to know how to generate the signature without using packages**, I want to share with you something that worked for me (using the package).

I wanted to use **Guzzle** to test how the Twitter API works through Laravel.

And since what I wanted to do was like a Tweet so I did it as follows. Using abraham/twitteroauth package.

So I separated my code a bit.

```
private function getApplicationInfo(){
      //Aplication information
      $api_key = 'twitter_api_key';
      $api_key_secret = 'twitter_api_key_secret';
    
      $credentials = [
         'api_key' => $api_key,
         'api_key_secret' => $api_key_secret,
      ];
    
      return $credentials;
   }
```

//Then I called this data from another method

```
public function likeTweet(){
      $application_info = $this->getApplicationInfo();
      $user = User::whereId(2)->first(); 
      $user_info = json_decode($user->user_info, true);

      
      $twitter_info = new TwitterOAuth(
         $application_info['api_key'], 
         $application_info['api_key_secret'], 
         $user_info['oauth_token'], $user_info['oauth_token_secret']
      );

      $twitter_info->setApiVersion('2');
    
      $data = [
         'tweet_id' => '1463484369100853255' //Tweet to which you are going to RT or like
      ];

      //The ID of the user who is going to like or RT
      $statues = $twitter_info->post("users/twitter_user_id/retweets", $data, true); // Note the true
   }
```

Note: My user 2 has a JSON field with the information like this

```
{"oauth_token": "user_id_twitter-token", "oauth_token_secret": "twitter_user_token_secret"}
```